# Any suggestions on many users uploading lots of large photos?

Tags: php, image, upload, gd

I am building a web application that allows the user to upload high res images (in the ballpark of 10mb). After its uploaded it creates a medium sized and thumbnail sized image of the upload. It seems it takes upwards of 100mb to of memory allocated to PHP just to resize to the medium image. I don't have a lot of experience in this type of scalability, will the site easily crash? Will I need webservers with 16gb of memory just to handle the load of the resizing? Are there alternative? Any information would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a queue of images to be resized and ensure that only x number of images are being resized at any given time. `x` would depend on the amount of available memory.

If you resize the images in real time as soon as they are uploaded, you are bound to run into a situation where more images are being resized than your memory can hold, which would cause a crash.

Instead, as the image are uploaded, add them to a DB. Then have a PHP script which fetches x images from the DB, forks new processes for each of these images to rezize them. As and when  a process report completion to the parent, the parent deletes the image's entry from the queue and fetches another. Wash, rinse, repeat.

Answer (score 0):

- run benchmarks
- do processing in the background
- do processing during off-peak hours
- use lighter libraries

Comment: What are some lighter libraries? Currently I use GD because it is what my hosting provider has

Comment: sorry, didn't mean to imply that I know, I just imagine that running GD thru php is probably not optimal for batch processing